# How can I center a middle column in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

My problem is: The output should show 2 side bars (column 0 and 2) with content Labels and Entrys and one central Window(column 1) much bigger than the other side bars in the middle. But the middle column always appears on the right side and as a very little frame.
Pls help.

My code and a picture:[image: What it looks]

```
import tkinter as tk, tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("THE FRIDGER")


root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

#prepared data
dflt = dict(fg="white", bg="black")
pads = dict(pady=4, padx=4)

#header frame
header = tk.Frame(root, bg="black")
header.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="nsew")

for i in range(2):
    header.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

#header labels
tk.Label(header, text="Fridge", **dflt).grid(column=0, row=0, **pads)
tk.Label(header, text="Recipes", **dflt).grid(column=1, row=0, **pads)


#separator
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('custom.TSeparator', background='blue')
ttk.Separator(root, style='custom.TSeparator').grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="ew")


#left side content
l_content = tk.Frame(root, bg="black")
l_content.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew")

tk.Label(l_content, text="Content:", **dflt).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W)

l_query = tk.Entry(l_content, width=36, relief=tk.FLAT, bg = "white", fg = "black")
l_query.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W)


#right side content
r_content = tk.Frame(root, bg="black")
r_content.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="nsew")

tk.Label(r_content, text="Content:", **dflt).grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.W)

r_query = tk.Entry(r_content, width=36, relief=tk.FLAT, bg = "white", fg = "black")
r_query.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.W)


#middle content

m_content = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
m_content.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="nsew")

tk.Label(m_content, text="This should appear in the middle", **dflt).grid(column=0, row=2,       sticky=tk.W)

m_content.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)





root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the left column is so large is that you are giving it a weight of 1. If you want the center column to take up all of the extra space, you need to give it a positive weight instead of giving the weight to column 0.

```
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You set `weight=1` on wrong column:

- `root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` should be `root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)`
- `m_content.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)` should be `m_content.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`

And remove `sticky` option from:

```
tk.Label(m_content, text="This should appear in the middle", **dflt).grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.W)
```